# How to add authority header to grpc ruby client stub?

Tags: ruby, grpc

I need to add authority header to ruby grcp stub. The stub is defined below:

```
stub = Sample::Stub.new(config.grpc_host, :this_channel_is_insecure)
```

Answer (score 1):

The authority header can be set at a channel or level, with the "grpc.default_authority" "channel arg". See https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/include/grpc/impl/codegen/grpc_types.h#L233

For example, you could tweak the "greeter client" (https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/ruby/greeter_client.rb) a custom authority with this snippet:

```
def main
  stub = Helloworld::Greeter::Stub.new('localhost:50051', :this_channel_is_insecure, channel_args: {'grpc.default_authority': 'my-authority'})
  user = ARGV.size > 0 ?  ARGV[0] : 'world'
  message = stub.say_hello(Helloworld::HelloRequest.new(name: user), metadata: {}).message
  p "Greeting: #{message}"
end
```